# TCPDF + pChart wont show images

Tags: image, pdf, tcpdf, pchart

I'm triying to insert a image on the pdf generated by the script.

I have put a image that is on the folder and it shows correctly, but the generated one no.

In other section of the site, I use the same function to generate and show the image and it shows correctly, only when I put on the pdf gets a blank gap.

```
$html1 = '
<p align="left" style="color:#434343;">
<span align="justify" style="color:#fe5a1d; font-size:35px;">3.3.- Comparativa Evaluación Tu Total – Evaluación media Total</span>
</p>
<p align="justify" style="color:#434343; font-size:34px;">
<img src="'.DOMINIO.'intranet/graph.php?ide='.$evaluacion->getId().'&tipo=3" border="0" width="700" height="230"/>
</p>
<p align="left" style="color:#434343;">
<span style="color:#fe5a1d; font-weight:bold;">4.- Detalle por competencias</span>
</p>
<p align="justify" style="color:#434343; font-size:34px;">
<img src="'.DOMINIO.'intranet/graph.php?ide='.$evaluacion->getId().'&tipo=4" border="0" width="700" height="230"/><br />
</p>
```

This is the code that makes a little paragraph that is shown on the PDF, the text works nice, it's only the image not shown.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now its solved, what i've done is render the images on the HardDisk and load it on the pdf

Comment: What do you mean "render on the hard disk"?  Is that a change in using tcpdf?

Comment: What I think he means is he renders the chart, saves it as an image, then loads the image into TCPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a problem with your PHP setup, specifically make sure you have support for GD image installed and enabled.

Comment: The php generates correctly the image, because in the web section it shows the charts correctly, is on the moment of including on the pdf that doesnt shows anything